# Parsing JSON response from a REST API call

Tags: javascript, api

I'm quite new to using APIs.

I am trying to take the response Text and sort info from it into different areas of a card. I'm not asking for a quick answer, but rather some documentation that I can go over to get a full understanding.

```js
var stat = document.getElementById('infoboxName');
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      method = "GET",
      url = "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/124";

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        stat.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        resolve("resolve");

      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  }, 300);
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);


});
```

```html
<div id='infoboxName'></div>
```

response output

```
{
  "url": "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/124",
  "name": "Antario Jast",
  "gender": "Male",
  "culture": "",
  "born": "",
  "died": "",
  "titles": [
    "Lord"
  ],
  "aliases": [
    ""
  ],
  "father": "",
  "mother": "",
  "spouse": "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/616",
  "allegiances": [
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/212"
  ],
  "books": [
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/2",
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/3",
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/5",
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/8"
  ],
  "povBooks": [],
  "tvSeries": [
    ""
  ],
  "playedBy": [
    ""
  ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to sort?

Comment: Please paste the response output so we know what we're working with.

Comment: Hey Darren, it sounds like what you really want to do is to parse the data...not sort it. Do you know in advance the structure of the info? Does it have known 'sections'?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to fire that request inside a timeout? If not, it's just pausing for 300ms for no reason, so just take what's inside the function in `setTimeout` and move it out (and remove the call to `setTimeout`).

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do with the result, but the `value` argument in the callback function (`then`) at the bottom is whatever you're sending as a parameter to the `resolve` call above. It will be called at the right time, but you'll only be logging "resolve" by then. If you want to use the actual result, use `resolve(xhr.responseText)` above instead;

Comment: Aha - just looked at the data being returned from the API. It looks like you should be able to access it as JSON. What exactly are the 'areas' you are trying to put it into?

Comment: thank ya'll for the quick responses. I'll try and better clarify what this is going to be used for.  basically I want to put the info into a character card I'm building. basically I just want Name, Gender, etc.

Comment: @Ele I'm just trying to have my response give me Name, Gender, and culture.  I'm probably over-complicating it in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want to do is parse that response, for doing that you can use `JSON.parse` which converts a JSON string into a JS Object.

After parsing that JSON string, you can access the data using the specific properties like `name` and `gender`.

On the other hand, I think you don't need that `setTimeout` at all.

*This example parses the JSON string and gets the `name` and `gender`, likewise through the function `resolve` I'm passing the parsed JSON string as JS Object.*

```js
var nameElement = document.getElementById('name');
var genderElement = document.getElementById('gender');

var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/124";

  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  nameElement.textContent = value.name;
  genderElement.textContent = value.gender;
});
```

```html
<div id='infoboxName'>
  <span id='name'></span>
  <p/>
  <span id='gender'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good thing that you're getting familiar with `XMLHttpRequest`, but for the sake of simplicity it's probably a good idea to start with a simpler syntax:

```
var stat = document.getElementById('infoboxName');
var apiResponse = await fetch("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/124");
var jsonParsedContents = await apiResponse.json(); // This is also a promise so must also wait for it

console.log(jsonParsedContents); // Do whatever you need with the object
```

If for some reason you cannot use `fetch` and must stick to `XMLHttpRequest`, then it's the value passed in your call to `resolve` you want to change:

```
var stat = document.getElementById('infoboxName');
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = "GET",
        url = "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/124";

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
});

promise1.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    // In here you'll probably want to stat.innerHTML = <some part of result>
});
```

In the code above I'm also assuming you want the promise to be handled in a different piece of code from where the API request is being sent, but if not, then you don't need that either and can simply do what you need with the response inside your `if`.